# HTML- iframe photo issue

Tags: html, css, iframe

So here's my issue: I have four photos in the bottom left side of my page, what I'm trying to do is have my mouse hover over one of the pictures and have a bigger picture of that image appear in my iframe. I have to do this without Javascript since it's for one of my classes but I just can't figure out how to do it in html. Here is my code:

```
<iframe name="lrgpic" src="Pacific files/images/photo2.jpg" width="500px" height="200px"></iframe>
<a href="Pacific files/images/photo2.jpg" target="lrgpic" onmouseover="this.click()">
    <img src="Pacific files/image/photo2thumb.jpg" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
</a>   
<table>
    <tr id="top">
        <td>
            <img src="Pacific files/images/photo2thumb.jpg" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <img src="Pacific files/images/photo3thumb.jpg" alt="Pacific" height="100px" />
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="bottom">
        <td>
            <img src="Pacific files/images/photo4thumb.jpg" alt="Pacific" height="100px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="Pacific files/images/photo6thumb.jpg" alt="Pacific" height="100px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 430px;
    left: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the images in the table as links. Define a separate classes for them. Then make every one appear in the iframe like you did with the link image. You can put the cursor property of the default to disguise them as pure images.

```css
table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 430px;
    left: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hello{
    cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="lrgpic" src="http://goo.gl/iVNwxy" width="500px" height="200px"></iframe>

<a href="http://goo.gl/bKfNtp" target="lrgpic"  onmouseover="this.click()">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/bKfNtp" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
</a>  

<table>
    <tr id="top">
        <td>
            <a href="http://goo.gl/fo9jcw" class="hello" target="lrgpic" onmouseover="this.click()">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/fo9jcw" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
                </a>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <a href="http://goo.gl/wlVZBm" class="hello" target="lrgpic" onmouseover="this.click()">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/wlVZBm" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
                </a>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="bottom">
        <td>
            <a href="http://goo.gl/FnYGrM" class="hello" target="lrgpic" onmouseover="this.click()">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/FnYGrM" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
                </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://goo.gl/8UaNCE" class="hello" target="lrgpic" onmouseover="this.click()">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/8UaNCE" alt ="Pacific" height="100px"/>
                </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```